# Loading php info into html doc using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I am very new to using AJAX and am experiencing problems using it to load data from the php handler file into html div element after the user clicks a portion of an svg image.

HTML code -- to be updated by the ajax once php sends db info

```
<div  class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 exercises">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Exercises</h2>
    <div  class="exercise-list">                    
     <?php //$exercises->getExercises($result); ?>
      <div class='media'><h3 id="exercise-list">Pick a muscle</h3>
      </div>                    
    </div>
</div>
```

ExerciseHandler.php -- having trouble figuring out what goes in $_GET or should I use a different method?

```
<?php
 require_once "Exercises.class.php";
 include 'dbconnect.php';

 $connect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

 $sql = "SELECT Muscle, Exercise, ImgResource, Descrip FROM exercises";
 $result = $connect->query($sql);

 if(isset( $_GET[''] )) {
   $exercises = new Exercises();
   $exercises->getExercises($result);
}
?>
```

Exercise.class.php

```
class Exercises {
public function getExercises($result) {        
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                                         
            echo    "<div class='media'>";
            echo        "<div class='media-object pull-left'>";
            echo            "<a href='#'><img src='".$row["ImgResource"]."' class='img-responsive' alt='curl'></a>";
            echo        "</div>";
            echo        "<div class='media-body'>";
            echo            "<h4 class='media-heading'><a href='#'>".$row["Exercise"]."</a></h4>";
            echo        "</div>";
            echo    "</div>";
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

loadExercises.js

```
function getExercises(clicked_muscle){
var muscle = clicked_muscle;
    alert("You selected" + muscle);

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    //modern browsers
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
    // code for old IE browsers
    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} 

ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("exercise-list").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    };

}

ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ExerciseHandler.php", true);
ajaxRequest.send();


}
```

Getexercises function. one of the facts for the muscle

```
 public function getExercises($result) {        
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                                         
                echo    "<div class='media'>";
                echo        "<div class='media-object pull-left'>";
                echo            "<a href='#'><img src='".$row["ImgResource"]."' class='img-responsive' alt='curl'></a>";
                echo        "</div>";
                echo        "<div class='media-body'>";
                echo            "<h4 class='media-heading'><a href='#'>".$row["Exercise"]."</a></h4>";
                echo        "</div>";
                echo    "</div>";
            }
        }

    }
```

Here is a screenshot [image: Muscles facts]

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Where are you call jquery function "getExercises"?

Comment: The error i get is that the html div does not change with the information that was gathered by the php file. 

"getExercises" comes from the PHP file. I want that output to be passed to the AJAX file which will then be used to change the text of the HTML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that worked

```
 $("#Biceps").click(function(){
  $.get("ExerciseHandler.php", function(data, status){
     $("#exercise-list").html(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code.

**HTML code** I have made some change in this file for the select option and call jquery function for ajax called.

```
<div  class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 exercises">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Exercises</h2>
    <div  class="exercise-list"> 
        <select onchange="getExercises(this)">
            <option value="1">Test</option>
            <option value="2">Test2</option>
        </select>                 
     <?php //$exercises->getExercises($result); ?>
      <div class='media'><h3 id="exercise-list">Pick a muscle</h3>
      </div>                    
    </div>
</div>
```

**loadExercises.js** I have pass data in GET method.

```
function getExercises(clicked_muscle){
    var muscle = set.value;;
    alert("You selected" + muscle);
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        //modern browsers
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } else {
        // code for old IE browsers
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } 

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("exercise-list").innerHTML=this.responseText;
        };

    }
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ExerciseHandler.php?value="+muscle, true);
    ajaxRequest.send();
}
```

**ExerciseHandler.php**

```
<?php
    require_once "Exercises.class.php";
    include 'dbconnect.php';

    $connect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $sql = "SELECT Muscle, Exercise, ImgResource, Descrip FROM exercises";
    $result = $connect->query($sql);

    if(isset($_GET) && !empty($_GET)) {
        $exercises = new Exercises();
        $exercises->getExercises($result);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Thanks to it i just realized part of my error. Im guessing the $_GET function is only used on Form items. What would be the best approach to get ajax to display the text I have in the getExercises method?

Comment: @BMLGLearning Can you please explain to me what you want?

Comment: Yes I can and thank you for taking the time. I have an image of all the muscles in the body. That image has an overlay of svg file groups. When I click on any svg group, I want the page to display different facts about that muscle on a div to the right of it using ajax as I do not want to load the entire page using php. The facts about the body part are stored in a mysql database. I dont use Jquery bc I know it doesnt interact well with SVG files. Hope that helps

Comment: Done. Thank you again for the help

Comment: Ok, What I understand. If any user clicks on any muscles of body part then we need show HTML(from PHP file) over (this muscles part details). Like I click on the left hand then show left-hand muscle details(from PHP by ajax call with page reload).  Right?

Comment: Yes. It will provide different facts about each muscle. There are many facts for each muscle so many divs will be used. Thats why i have a while loop in the getExercises method. Ill add that portion right away.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187349/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-bmlg-learning).